# How to appropriately scale confidence intervals

Tags: confidence-interval, variance

Suppose I have a point estimate and its standard deviation: $\mu_1 = 0.3$ ($\sigma_1 = 0.1$). I know sample size $n_1 = 100$, so its Wald CI is $[0.3 - 1.96 \times 0.1/10 = 0.28, 0.3 + 1.96 \times 0.1/10 = 0.32)$

Now suppose I have another point estimate ($\mu_2 = 0.3$) from another population $n_2 = 50$, but I do not have information on its variance. My goal is to construct a CI for this point estimate too. Assuming that the distribution is the same as the population mentioned above, I would like to scale the variance (or CI) somehow to reflect the smaller sample size.

Since $n_1$ is twice that of $n_2$, then would it be appropriate to just double the standard deviation? But that doesn't necessarily ensure the corresponding CI to be bounded correctly between 0 and 1?

Comment: Why do you think the CI should lie entirely between 0 and 1?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to clarify, my point estimates represent probability of having a disease. So they must be bounded between 0 and 1

Comment: I suspected something like that... first, your rescaling of the standard deviation would be by the square root of the ratio of the sample sizes, not the ratio itself.  Second, the Wald CI is asymptotically accurate, so there's no guarantee that it won't overlap the $(0,1)$ bounds with finite sample sizes.  I have to admit, though, that I don't know how to construct a CI in your case that would have the finite-sample properties you want and be roughly correct as to level without having a probability distribution for the data.